# WP OptionTree plguin update data

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to update option tree data when theme switch.
by using this code i'm getting the option tree data.

```
ot_get_option('site_paypalmail','',TRUE)
```

just i need to know have there any function like **ot_set_option()**

Thanks

Comment: `ot_get_option()` is not an official Wordpress function. You have to be a little clearer. Is it a theme or a plugin and what's the name of it?

Comment: It's a function from plguin which name is OptionTree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there have no any built-in function by OptionTree but you can try my code which i used several times.

```
$option_tree = get_option('option_tree');
$option_tree['customa_name'] = 'Your Value';
update_option('option_tree', $option_tree);
```

Comment: Thanks, let me try it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no. There are no functions like *ot_set_option()* or *ot_update_option()*.

But this is what the function `ot_get_option()` is doing:

```
function ot_get_option( $option_id, $default = '' ) {

/* get the saved options */ 
$options = get_option( ot_options_id() );

/* look for the saved value */
if ( isset( $options[$option_id] ) && '' != $options[$option_id] ) {

  return ot_wpml_filter( $options, $option_id );

}

return $default;

}
```

That means it is getting the ID with `get_option( ot_options_id() );`.

`get_option()` is an official Wordpress function. In this case you could also use `update_option()` to set your own option ID.